# Does bash create a child process to run every command

Tags: bash

Every time we run a normal command like `ps` multiple times, it has different process ids (PID). I wanted to know if that means for every command we run in terminal (bash) it creates a child process of bash to execute that command.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, pretty much every command you'd run on the command line runs in a process of its own, and those processes are children of the shell launching them.

The exception here are builtin commands of the shell. Bash implements some standard utilities itself, like `printf`, `echo`, `true`, `false`, `kill` and `[`/`test`, so running those doesn't involve forking a child. The same applies to things like `cd`, `read` and `mapfile`, though they affect the shell's internal state, so they have to be builtin.

<sub>(Also `break`, `continue`, and `return`, which oddly enough are builtin utilities, not shell keywords like `if` and `while`.)</sub>

There's really no way for the shell to run an external program in the same process with itself, while still being able to go back. It is however possible for the shell to *replace* itself with another program. E.g. if you run `echo $$` to see the PID of the shell and subsequently run `exec ps`, you'll see `ps` running with the same PID. And when `ps` exits, that shell no longer exists. Actually, a similar thing happens every time you run a program in the normal way, just that the shell makes a copy of itself (the `fork()` system call) before replacing the child with the program to run (`execve()`). In between the shell program running in the child process takes care of setting up any redirections and such for the child.

It would be possible for a shell to implement other tools as builtins too, e.g. Busybox implements are largish set of standard utilities in the same program file. But as far as I tested, it still forks a child when running them, probably since it's an easy way to ensure the utilities don't mess with the shell's state unnecessarily.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, for *almost* any command [1].

Except for the commands implemented as built-ins, the list of which you can get with `help` in bash [2].

Notice that bash also forks when running subshells, even if they only run builtins; e.g. in `(echo a | read p)` you have 3 separate processes on top of the one running the main shell.

[1] The initial idea with the very first Unix shell (the Thompson shell) was that *all* commands should be separate binaries and run as separate processes. However, design limitations and implementation quirks caused that to quicky fall apart, as first `chdir` had to be implemented as a built-in, then the variable assignments, and so on. Further shells eroded the initial idea more and more.

[2] Even when running buitins, bash tries to mimic separate processes; for instance the redirection from `echo > file` is handled in a totally different (and very complicated) way than the one from `ls > file` in order to maintain the illusion that `echo` runs just as a separate command, and the redirection doesn't apply to the entire shell, but only to the `echo` command. Bash does not always get that right; for instance, in

```
bash -c 'trap "echo Ctrl-C" INT; read p; echo DONE'
```

the `INT` trap will not be executed *after* the `read` command has returned, as it would happen with any other command (other shells like dash do get that right). Also, a blocking built-in `echo` may return with a silly "Interrupted system call" something that an external `/bin/echo` will never do (since `echo` doesn't have to and doesn't set any signal handler ;-)) -- and thousands of similar cases where the kludge shows through the seams.

NB: busybox has nothing to do with this -- busybox is an example of multi-call binary, a program which can execute different functions depending on the first command line argument; just like `ex/vi`, `od/hexdump`, etc. However, the applets from busybox (including its shells, `ash` and `hush`) are able to run *some* other applets as same process built-ins, if expressly compiled that way (the [`NOFORK/NOEXEC`](https://git.busybox.net/busybox/tree/NOFORK_NOEXEC.lst) applets).

Comment: (echo a | read p) you have 3 separate processes on top of the one running the main shell.
Why three? should be two current shell with "echo a" and child with "read p"

Comment: No, they're three (four if you also count the main shell). There's one process for the subshell created by the parens (`(...)`), one for the left side (`...|`) of the pipeline, and one for the right side (`|...`).

Answer (score -2):

Most normal things you run in bash do get a new PID because they are different processes (a process starts with a given PID, it runs, then it finishes, the PID is available for a new process... eventually... check `zombie processes`). There are some builtins that are directly run by bash without creating a new process (echo, for example).... and then there are some things that create bash subprocesses (each with their own PID, like `while read`, that won't allow you to set the value of a variable inside the while to use it outside because the new value dies when `while` is done).

Comment: There's nothing special about `while`, it doesn't create a subshell by itself. You're thinking of pipes `a | b | c | while read ...; done` -- each command in a pipeline runs in a separate subshell. See [3.2.3 Pipelines](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pipelines) in the manual

Comment: This does not answer whether each command that is executed is started by first starting a `bash` shell process to execute it, which seems to be the question. I don't know if the user in the question wonders whether `fork()` is called internally, which in effect creates a copy of the shell process, or whether they think `bash` invokes the `bash` utility to run each command.

Comment: @glennjackman That is great insight. Let me adjust that in my answer